# Conflict jquery libs

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

is the following I have 2 scripts one playlist and other notifications in real time and uses this lib PlayList:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
and the notification of this:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js and when the lib is in the playlist code notifications not run and if I take wheel but I want the two working, how do I?

Comment: Remove one of them (preferably the 1.4) and edit the code for the deprecated jquery parts.

Comment: how to edit the code for the deprecated jquery parts?

Comment: you have to go thru the code and find the "old" jQuery methods. You can ask here or in codereview if you have specific code to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both libraries, this is the way to call those libs.

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script> var jq110 = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script> var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

So, when you are going to call the library you use `jq110` instead the `$` sign and for the notification script use `jq142` instead the `$` sign again.